# Why do we count up (1-49) instead of counting down (49-1)?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, shavuos

I've heard an answer that makes a comparison to the reasoning for why we light Channukah candles upwards (**1-8**) from [Shabbat 21b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.21b.5-6?lang=bi):

> מעלין בקדש ואין מורידין
>
> "we go up in holiness and don't decrease"

- Is that legitimately the reason for our practice of counting upwards **1-49**?
- Are there additional reason(s) for counting upwards **1-49**,
  perhaps brought down by the Talmud/ Rishonim/ early Acharonim etc?

Comment: @DonielF yep that's pretty much the same, thanks for sharing. The issue is that that question doesn't satisfactorily answer my question (at least not with sources), and if we mark as duplicate then no one really will address it. It's all good, those *he'aros* feel like they're more for meta

Comment: That’s what Meta is for. MY is by the community, for the community - if you have what to share about policy, speak up!

Comment: @alicht: The time span in question lasts for seven weeks of seven days each, and, in [Hebrew, weekdays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_the_days_of_the_week#Days_numbered_from_Sunday) are (obviously) counted upwards, not downwards; so, in the first week, the reckoning starts and ends normally, like in any other week, but afterwards, instead of resetting, as it usually would, continues to increase, until it finally reaches 49.